# Get text value from a button s created dynamically jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script

So i am dynamically adding buttons to a table based on array values returned from my generateFolderTree function, problem is i can't seem to get the text value of a clicked button or even get any events when i click the created buttons. How can i get the name of a clicked button? Code below....Thanks

Jquery

```
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
$("#selectFolder").click(runMyFunction);
});
function runMyFunction(){
google.script.run
.withSuccessHandler(successCallback)
.withFailureHandler(showError)
.generateFolderTree();
 $("#hiddenAttrib").hide();
}

function showError(error) {
    console.log(error);
    window.alert('An error has occurred, please try again.');
  }
  function successCallback(returnedArray)
  {
    console.log("returnedArray" + returnedArray);
    var folders = returnedArray;
   console.log("folders" + folders);
    var i = 0;
    //row;
    for( i=0; i<folders.length;i++)
    {
       console.log("i = " + i);
   var row = $('<p><tr><button class = "selectedFolder">' + folders[i] + '</button></tr></p>');
    $("#source").append(row.html());
    }
  }
 $(".selectedFolder").click(function () {
var text = $(this).text();
console.log(text);
$("#dialog-status").val(text);
}); 


</script>
```

Show.html

```
   <!-- USe a templated HTML printing scriphlet to import common stylesheet. -->
<?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("Stylesheet").getContent(); ?>
<!-- Use a templated HTML printing scriptlet to import JavaScript. -->

<div>
<div class = "block" id = "dialog-elements">
<button class = "selectFolder" id = "selectFolder" >Select a Folder</button>
</div>
<!-- This block is going to be hidden until the user selects a folder -->
<div class = "block" id = "hiddenAttrib">
<p><label for = "SelectedFolder"> Selected Folder: </label></p>
<p><label id = "foldername"> Folder Name: </label></p>
<p><label id = "folderid"> Folder ID: </label></p>
</div>
<div class = "folderTable" id = "folderTable">
<p><label class = "showStatus" id = "dialog-status">Selected Folder: </label></p>
<table style = "width:100%" id = "source">

</table>


</div>

</div>
<!-- Use a templated HTML printing scriptlet to import JavaScript. -->
<?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('ShowJavaScript').getContent(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('document').on('click', '.selectedFolder', function () {

            alert($(this).text())
        });
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you also explained *why* rather than just a code blob...

Answer (score 0):

Put this piece of code of yours in $(document).ready

```
$(".selectedFolder").click(function () {
var text = $(this).text();
console.log(text);
$("#dialog-status").val(text);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$(ELEMENT/CLASS/ID).on('click', function(){});
```

instead of

```
$(ELEMENT/CLASS/ID).click
```

`click()` function doesnt consider elements added to DOM dynamically before we used to use `live()` for attaching events for dynamically created element but since `live()` is depreciated we should use on()

`on()` acts as `live()`

Comment: still doesn't work, when i use $('button'), all other buttons work except the ones created dynamically, did i create the dynamic buttons in a wrong way?